# Transform the text representation of a timespan in shell script

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a program that outputs a time in the format

```
2s576039936ns
```

I need to convert this to the following format:

```
2.576039936
```

How can I do this in shell script?

**Update:** Please note that the `ns` part is not padded to 9 digits, so output like `2s513ns` can occur and should be transformed to `2.000000513`.

Comment: The answer depends very much. As you know, shell variables are untyped. Do you simply want to transform the text representation, or do you intend to perform floating-point arithmetic with the result? If so, please note that the shell is not designed for that.

Comment: Shell only understands integers. There's nothing like a float in a shell. You can change a string, but you can't make it a float.

Comment: @choroba, *`bash`* only understands integers. But several other shells (`ksh93`, `zsh`, `yash`, `fish`) don't have that limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems you only want to transform the "text representation", you can pipe the output of the command through `sed`. The following command first removes `ns` and then replaces `s` by a `.`:

```
~$ echo "2s576039936ns" | sed -e 's/ns//' -e 's/s/./'
2.576039936
```

**Update**

In a comment you stated that the nanosecond part is not zero-padded to exactly 9 digits. In that case, the output will be incorrect. To remedy, you can use the following `awk` solution:

```
~$ echo "2s576039936ns" | awk -F'n?s' '{printf "%d.%09d\n",$1,$2}'
```

This will use either `s` or `ns` as field separator (multi-character field separators will be interpreted as regular expression, not merely as multi-character string), and print fields one and two (the latter now zero-padded to 9 decimals) with `.` as separator.

So in your script, you could use

```bash
t=$( your_command | awk -F'n?s' '{printf "%d.%09d\n",$1,$2}' )
```

Answer (score 7):

This solution will handle `2s576039936ns` as well as `2s123ns`:

```bsh
$ echo 2s576039936ns | tr '[:alpha:]' ' ' | awk -- '{ printf "%d.%09d",$1,$2 }'
2.576039936

$ echo 2s123ns | tr '[:alpha:]' ' ' | awk -- '{ printf "%d.%09d",$1,$2 }'
2.000000123
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use this feature of Bash (not sure if this is POSIX):

```
x=2s576039936ns
y=${x/s/.}
z=${y/ns/}
echo $z
```

Or `sed`:

```
echo 2s576039936ns | sed 's/s/./; s/ns//'
```

Both methods first replace the s with a dot, then remove the ns.

And for something completely different:

```
echo 2s576039936ns | awk -F '[ns]' '{print $1 "." $2}'
```

This is assuming you only want to change the *format* and not the numbers.

Comment: `${param/pattern/replacemen}` is from ksh93 and has not been added to the [POSIX sh specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) (contrary to `${param#pattern}` for instance which is from ksh88).

Comment: Also assumes that the `ns` value has been written with zero padding (`%09d`).

Answer (score 4):

With `perl`:

```
$ echo 10000s12576039936ns 1s1ns 0001s1000000ns 12s0ns |
   perl -Mbignum -pe 's{(\d+)s(\d+)ns}{$1 + $2 / 1e9}ge'
10012.576039936 1.000000001 1.001 12
```

Note that arbitrary precision (here using `bignum` in `perl`) is generally needed when dealing with second+nanosecond values in arithmetic operations,  like in the `struct timespec` manipulated by `clock_gettime()` for instance if you want to preserve precision up to the nanosecond as your processor/C compiler's `double` type generally used by tools that do arithmetics (`awk`, `perl` without `bignum`, shells...) don't have enough precision.

With `zsh`:

```
string='10000s12576039936ns 1s1ns 0001s1000000ns 12s0ns'

set -o extendedglob
newstring=${string//(#b)(<->)s(<->)ns/\
$((match[1] + match[2] / 10**9))${${:-.${(l[9][0])match[2]}}%%(.|)0#}}
```

Would give you `10012.576039936 1.000000001 1.001 12` in `$newstring` as well (here using integer arithmetic on the two numbers as `zsh` also uses `double` for its floats).

Answer (score 2):

if using `awk` is also an option:

```
awk -F'n?s' '$0=$1"."$2'
```

The `n?s` defined as field seperator sets both `ns` or `s` strings as the FS; it's ERE that means optional `n` followed by an `s` character which every *awk* supports FS to be defined as Extended Regular Expression.

Answer (score 1):

Another copuple of ways in `bash`:

For **this** specific purpose this work:

```
echo "${value%%s*}.${value:2:${#value}-4}"
```

For similar case, with more precision for the real part of the integer:

```
[[ $value =~ ^([[:digit:]]+)s([[:digit:]]+)ns$ ]]
new_value="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With a POSIX shell - or `bash` for that matter - you cannot transform the number in one step. Here I've replaced the `s` with a decimal point and then stripped the `ns`

```
v='2s576039936ns'

t="${v%%s*}.${v#*s}"
t="${v%ns}"

echo "$t"
2.576039936
```

You've tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) so you can simplify a little, but it still takes two steps

```
v='2s576039936ns'

t="${v%ns}"
t="${t/s/.}"

echo "$t"
2.576039936
```

Alternatively, jump out to an external command and do it all in one step

```
v='2s576039936ns'

t=$(echo "$v" | sed -E sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+)s(([[:digit:]]+)ns)?/\1.\3/')

echo "$t"
2.576039936
```